# cts query to filter documents from a particular collection for the last 24 hours

Tags: javascript, marklogic

I have been trying to find the documents from a particular collection based on the field report_time.

I have been trying the below query. But, it doesn't work.

```
cts.andQuery(cts.collectionQuery('myCollection'),cts.jsonPropertyRangeQuery("report_time", ">", new Date(Date.now() - 86400 * 1000).toISOString()))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? When you say "it doesn't work", do you mean that it isn't filtering and returning the expected results, that you are getting an error (if so, what is the error), or it is returning nothing at all? You posted a `cts.andQuery()` can we assume that it is being applied to a `cts.search()`?

Comment: @Mads Hansen I was trying to apply it to the sourceQuery of the mapping step in the datahub. I wanted the mapping step to be run only on documents for the last 24 hours for a particular collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that snippet, the one thing that needs adjustment is that the query criteria need to be in an array for the `cts.andQuery()` param:

```
cts.andQuery([
  cts.collectionQuery('myCollection'),
  cts.jsonPropertyRangeQuery("report_time", ">", new Date(Date.now() - 86400 * 1000).toISOString())
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do the math, you can use an "age query".  See the end of the page at https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/rangequery